# heroku git dependency propagation

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

In my heroku app repo, we have git dependency

```
"allcountjs" : "git+https://gitlab.com/ourawesome/allcountjs.git#Print
```

I have made some changes to this repo (allcountjs ) and i want them reflected to my heroku app.

I did a git pull / git push on heroku and it seemed to have successfully deployed the app. Alas, I don't see the changes when i access the app on web.

**Any idea why? 
How can I force a node restart on a heroku app?**

I hope it s clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more like NPM issue than Heroku. Try putting the commit id instead of branch in the url of dependency, e.g.:

```
"dependency" : "git+https://gitlab.com/ourawesome/allcountjs.git#e1111a0a4cf50ae6ef1dde4c22b87d833e26befa"
```

So that NPM knows that it was updated